# Lista no deja agregar datos de un modelo que tienen 1 dato de otro modelo

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, model

estoy usando .net core 6, code first, tengo una lista de Songs que funcionaba bien cuando la incluía en una lista. Pero, incluí el Artist de la canción y ya la lista no deja ingresar.

Ensajé creando un modelo que tuviera lo de la canción y el Artist, pero tampoco funcionó.

```
var song = dataContext.Songs.Where(i => i.SongId == myNumber)
                        .Include(b => b.Artist.ArtistName);

if (song != null)
{
    songsList.AddRange(song.ToList<SongWithArtist>());         
}
```

Los modelos:

```
public class Song
    {     
        public int SongId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SongRegistryDate { get; set; }
        public string SongName { get; set; }
        public string SongLikes { get; set; }
        public string SongDislikes { get; set; }
        public string SongImageRoute { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

public class Artist
    {   
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    }
```

El Artist de Song creo que es una propiedad navegacional, no trae nada en el resultado.

Error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The expression 'b.Artist.ArtistName' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.

Alguna idea de como podria llenar una lista de Songs con el Artist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la expression del [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) va el objeto relacionado ("la tabla") No la propiedad de ese objeto.

Cambia esto

```
var song = dataContext.Songs.Where(i => i.SongId == myNumber)
                        .Include(b => b.Artist.ArtistName);
```

Por esto

```
var song = dataContext.Songs.Include(b => b.Artist).Where(i => i.SongId == myNumber);
```

(Yo siempre pongo el Include primero, pero según lo que entiendo no debería haber problema con colocarlo al final)

Comment: I tried @Yussef Error 500 in Postman: System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.Artist.Songs.SongId.

Comment: @JhonHernandez Ese es otro error y está relacionado con JSON. Tú tienes un modelo circular. Song tiene Artistas y Artistas tiene Song. Esto no es un problema para C# salvo cuando conviertes JSON. Recuerda que si esta respuesta te sirvió para el error que está en tu pregunta original, puedes darla como aceptada. Y para este otro error puede crear otra pregunta, ya que las reglas de SO no permiten varias preguntas